# 'float' object is not subscriptable error while trying to add data into a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file containing reviews. I want to calculate each review's sentiment polarity, and then output a new column that says if the review's sentiment is positive or negative

The Whole thing looks like this

```
filename = r'./DisneylandReviews.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='latin-1')

df.columns=['ID','rating','Date', 'Location','Review','Branch']

def Rating_To_Sent (row):
   if row['rating'] == 3 :
      return 'neutral'
   if row['rating'] < 3 :
      return 'negative'
   else:
      return 'positive'
  
df['RatingSentiment'] = df.apply (lambda row: Rating_To_Sent(row), axis=1)   



def sentiment_calc(text):
    try:
        return TextBlob(text).sentiment.polarity
    except:
        return None
    
df['sentiment']=df['Review'].apply(sentiment_calc)


 
def Review_To_Sent(row):
   if row ['sentiment'] < -0.05 :
      return 'negative'
   if row['sentiment'] > 0.05 :
      return 'positive'
   else:
      return 'neutral'
df['Review_Sentiment']=df['sentiment'].apply(Review_To_Sent)

x=df.loc[0:20,'sentiment']
print(x)
```

and this is the line thats producing an error

```
def Review_To_Sent(row):
   if row ['sentiment'] < -0.05 :
```

Comment: To the function, review_to_sent(row) you are not passing the whole row, you are passing only the row values of a particular column called sentiment so just remove [‘sentiment’] from the check condition.

Answer (score 0):

To the function, `review_to_sent(row)` you are not passing the whole row, you are passing only the row values of a particular column called sentiment so

Method 1:
Change calling methodology by doing apply on dataframe like

```
df.apply(Review_to_Sent(row))
```

Method 2:
Remove `row[‘sentiment’]` from the check condition.